# From a computer connected in Wifi, can I see the traffic of ethernet-connected computers, with Wireshark?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, wireshark

In the following network, if I open Wireshark on `ComputerA`, can I see the traffic of `ComputerB` (to internet) with Wireshark?

```
 ____________________
|    Home router     |
|  (provided by ISP) |
|   192.168.1.1      |
|____________________|    
  |             |
  |             |
  wifi          ethernet
  |             |
  |             |
 ComputerA     ComputerB
 192.168.1.2   192.168.1.3
```

Comment: Which traffic are you referring to? Only traffic between Computer A and Computer B? Also traffic between Computer B and the Internet (going through the home router)? Or any other traffic we should be aware of?

Comment: @Albin I'm speaking about traffic between `ComputerB` and internet, going through the home router.

Answer (score 2):

No, Wi-Fi APs (wireless routers) will not forward unicast traffic onto Wi-Fi unless it is addressed to a current Wi-Fi client. So for example ComputerB's Internet traffic could not be seen by ComputerA. But ComputerA would see any of ComputerB's broadcasts and most typical multicasts, plus any traffic between ComputerB and other devices on Wi-Fi.